# "Filename or extension too long" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile

I'm trying to create a StorageFile object from a URL, passing in a URI object with URL and opening a stream to it

```
StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), uri, RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri))
```

This triggers a "File name or extension too long" exception, with the filename (url) in question being 283 character long

I tried looking up [RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(Uri) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.randomaccessstreamreference.createfromuri?view=winrt-19041) and [StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(String, Uri, IRandomAccessStreamReference) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.createstreamedfilefromuriasync?view=winrt-19041) in MSDocs but none list any exception about it.

For reference, this is a Universal Windows Platform program, with Target 1903, min 1809

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://serverfault.com/questions/15357/ms-windows-issue-filename-or-extension-is-too-long

Comment: Although Windows and NTFS support very long file names, most of the traditional APIs support 254 chars max. I bet if you get a full stack (including managed and unmanaged code) from that exception, you'd find you are in one of those. Short answer... Use a shorter filename

Comment: @IronMan looks like the max_path limitation it is, except that solution isnt something UWP's restrictions will let through

Comment: @Flydog57 since the file name is a URL, coming from an API that isn't under my control, shortenning the file name isn't possible

Comment: MS "fixed" this but ... you must opt in to longer than 260 character file names per this: [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation).  However, most programs still cannot handle the longer file names and this would need to be  an opt in on all systems.  Not a good solution.  Do you have a way to abbreviate the file name?